# Continuous wavelet transform of a dataframe column

Tags: r, dataframe, continuous-integration, wavelet

I would like to perform the continuous wavelet transform (with mexican hat wavelet) of a time series stored in the column `price` of a dataframe like this:

```
 > df
  id time  price
1  1    0 222.19
2  1    1 220.42
3  1    2 224.95
4  1    3 225.74
```

I've not found a package to help me with this task and then I tried to write the code of integral form definition enclosed in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_wavelet_transform). Anyway, this is a problem for me because, e.g.

```
install.packages("pracma")
library("pracma")
fun <- function(x) **insert function here**
integral(fun, -1000, 1000, reltol = 1e-12, method = "Simpson")
```

allows us to estimate definite integral of a function, but I instead have an array (i.e. `price`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But, if you try to transform your list to a dataframe, wouldn't that be easier to evaluate for a function? what is the function of the transform of wavalet transform?

Comment: Hey, I´m searching, and I found something that will serve you; https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/wavelets/wavelets.pdf